# MVC 4 - pass parameter to controller on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 project that has a save button that when clicked asks the user to confirm and then submits the whole form back to the controller with the model as input, not formCollection.  Now I need to add another button to the form called Submit.  How can I pass a parameter to differentiate between Save and Submit?  I'd like to continue using the JQuery function for the confirmation.  Here are some code snippets:

```
JavaScript

function SavePlan() {
    if (ValidateAmounts() != true) {
    var message = "Do you want to save? ";
    CreateConfirmationMessage(message, '$("#form_FiscalYearPlanning").submit();');
    return;
}

}
```

JQUERY

```
function CreateConfirmationMessage(message, confirmActionToTake, cancelActionToTake) {

    $('#PROJECT_confirmationQuestion').html(message);

            if (confirmActionToTake !== null) {
        $('#button_confirmationAccept').attr('onClick', confirmActionToTake);
    }
            else {
        $('#button_confirmationAccept').removeAttr('onClick');
    }

            if (cancelActionToTake !== null) {
        $('#button_confirmationCancel').attr('onClick', cancelActionToTake);
    }
            else {
        $('#button_confirmationCancel').removeAttr('onClick');
    }
    $('#modal_confirmation').modal('show');
}/
```

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FiscalYearPlanning", "Teammanagement", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_FiscalYearPlanning" }))
```

:::

```
<button class="btn btn-primary PROJECT_formButtonPopover" id="button_SavePlan" name="button_SavePlan" onClick="SavePlan();" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Save your plan, but do not submit it for review.">Save</button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult FiscalYearPlanning(VM_FiscalYearPlanning model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input buttons have a value.  You can detect the value of the input button at the controller.

```
<input type="submit" value="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" value="savebutton">
```

Comment: I ran a quick test with my button defined like so:      <button class="btn btn-primary PROJECT_formButtonPopover" id="button_SavePlan" name="button_SavePlan" value="Save" onClick="SavePlan();" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Save your plan, but do not submit it for review.">Save</button> ...and my controller like so:   public ActionResult FiscalYearPlanning(VM_FiscalYearPlanning model, string button_SavePlan) but the button value is null in the controller

Comment: My bad.  I had moved the button outside of the form because the code goes straight to the controller and automatically starts saving the form without waiting for a response to the confirmation question.  Any ideas how to fix that?